# Loading C Library in Lua -llua not found

Tags: c, gcc, lua

I am trying to load a simple c function I wrote to lua so I can use it in my lua coding. I'm trying to compile it with: 
                `gcc ./main.c -llua -ldl -lm  -o lualibl`
and I'm receiving an error:

                `ld: library not found for -llua`
                `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Say I remove -llua, then all my luaL_checkinteger/luaL_setfuncs functions are undefined symbols so I'm assuming I need to compile with the lua library. Any ideas on how I can find this library to compile with my c code? I'm running lua 5.2

Comment: What about `-llua5.2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most probably missing lua shared library (liblua).
E.g. On my distro, correct package to install would be *liblua50-dev_5.0.3-7_amd64.deb* (or similar)

Comment: They come with "libluaxx-dev", which we must assume is installed otherwise the "`#include <lua.h>`" lines, etc, would generate errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might find you just need a versioned library:

```
 $ gcc ./main.c -llua5.2 -ldl -lm  -o lualibl
```